# AttributeError at /api/updateorder/71 'RelatedManager' object has no attribute 'save'

Tags: django, api, django-rest-framework, save, postman

I am trying to make update api for order objects. OrderItem model is in many to one relationship (with Foreignkey) with Order Model. Also, Billing Details model is one to one relationship with Order model. I am able to update Billing details fields and also Order fields, but cant update the OrderItem fields.

I got this error saying **'RelatedManager' object has no attribute 'save'**

My models:

```
class Order(models.Model):
    ORDER_STATUS = (
        ('To_Ship', 'To Ship',),
        ('Shipped', 'Shipped',),
        ('Delivered', 'Delivered',),
        ('Cancelled', 'Cancelled',),
    )
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True)    
    order_status = models.CharField(max_length=50,choices=ORDER_STATUS,default='To_Ship')

    ordered_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    ordered = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    total_price = models.CharField(max_length=50,blank=True,null=True)
    #billing_details = models.OneToOneField('BillingDetails',on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True,blank=True,related_name="order")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.email

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Orders"
        ordering = ('-id',)

class OrderItem(models.Model):
    #user = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True)
    order = models.ForeignKey(Order,on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True,null=True,related_name='order_items')
    item = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE,blank=True, null=True)
    order_variants = models.ForeignKey(Variants,on_delete=models.CASCADE,blank=True,null=True)
    quantity = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    # def price(self):
    #     total_item_price = self.quantity * self.item.varaints.price
    #     return total_item_price
    total_item_price = models.PositiveIntegerField(blank=True,null=True,)
    

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.quantity} items of {self.item} of {self.order.user}"

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Cart Items"
        ordering = ('-id',)

class BillingDetails(models.Model):
    PAYMENT_TYPE = (
        ('cash_on_delivery', 'Cash On Delivery',),
        ('credit/debit_card', 'Credit/Debit Card',),
        ('connect_ips', 'Connect IPS',),
        ('fonepay', 'Fonepay',),
    )
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True)
    order = models.OneToOneField(Order, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True, related_name='billing_details')  
    address = models.CharField(max_length=100,blank=True,null=True)
    postal = models.CharField(max_length=50,blank=True,null=True)
    payment_type = models.CharField(max_length=50,blank=True,null=True,choices=PAYMENT_TYPE,default='cash_on-delivery')
    def __str__(self):
        return self.address

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural= "Shipping Address"
```

MY VIEWS:

```
class UpdateOrderView(UpdateAPIView):
    permission_classes = [AllowAny]
    queryset = Order.objects.all()
    serializer_class = OrderUpdateSerializer
```

My serializers:

```
class OrderUpdateSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    order_items = OrderItemSerializer(many=True)
    billing_details = BillingDetailsSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = Order
        fields = ['ordered','order_status','order_items','billing_details']


    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        instance.order_status = validated_data.get('order_status')
        instance.ordered = validated_data.get('ordered')

        billing_details_data = validated_data.pop('billing_details',None)
        if billing_details_data is not None:
            instance.billing_details.address = billing_details_data['address']
            instance.billing_details.save() #no-error here


        order_items_data = validated_data.pop('order_items')
        for order_items_data in order_items_data:
            instance.order_items.quantity = order_items_data['quantity']
            instance.order_items.order_item_status = order_items_data['order_item_status']
            instance.order_items.save() #got the error here
            #super(OrderUpdateSerializer, self).update(instance.order_items,validated_data).save()
        #super().save()
        

        return super().update(instance,validated_data)
```

There is no error in `instance.billing_details.save()`, but the same code `instance.order_items.save()` generates the above error. If I remove instance.order_items.save(), then it works but it doesnt save the updated data in the db.

Comment: `instance.order_items` will give you a related manager not an instance of `OrderItem`.

Comment: Yes, I have put instance.order_items.save() . So, why the error?

Comment: `for order_items_data in order_items_data:` will not work, you are using the same variable in both places. This is not the direct cause of the error, but it also will prevent your code from working as intended.

Answer (score 2):

You are using `OneToOneField` in one but `ForeignKey` in the other model, so you cannot use the same code for both.

```
class OrderItem(models.Model):
    ...
    order = models.ForeignKey(..., related_name='order_items')
    ...
 
class BillingDetails(models.Model):
    ...
    order = models.OneToOneField(..., related_name='billing_details')  
    ...
```

The `instance.billing_details` will return an `BillingDetails` instance (if there is one) because it is a `OneToOneField`, but `instance.order_items` will return a related manager for `OrderItem`, not an instance.

Solutions:

1. change the field `OrderItem.order` to `OneToOneField`; but I don't know if that fits your use case, so you have to analyze it in detail if it will work for you.
2. `instance.order_items.first()` (or `instance.order_items.get(...)`) to get get an instance from the related manager.